# Populate form with data via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form that returns make and model data from an API call when a car registration number is entered, I was given javascript that shows this data as a simple alert but I need it instead to fill out another form on the page the code is;

```
<form name="enterRegForm" method="post" id="enterRegForm">
    <input type="text" id="inputReg" name="inputReg" maxlength= "12" placeholder="ENTER REG" style="width:122px;height:20px;margin:4px 0 0 19px;font:bold 18px tahoma, arial;border:0;text-align:center;"/>
    <input name="button" type="submit" value="Get Report" />
</form>
```

```js
var inputReg = $('#inputReg');
$('#enterRegForm').submit(function(){
    if (inputReg.val()) {
        $.getJSON("api-proxy.php", { reg: inputReg.val() }, function( data ) {
            // alert("Make: " + data['make'] + "\nModel: " + data['model']);
            alert(data.inspect());
        });
    } 
    else {
        alert('Please enter a registration number!');
    }
    return false;
})
```

So instead of the alert which shows Make and Model of the car (ie Make: Volkswagen Model:Golf) I need it to fill out two inputs in the second form named "car-make" and "car-model". What do I change to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: This should help you: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Can you show us the JSON returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

suppose you have input field with id car-make and car-model:

```
<input id="car-make" value="" name = "car-make">
<input id="car-model" value="" name = "car-model">
```

and js:

```
var inputReg = $('#inputReg');
$('#enterRegForm').submit(function(){
    if (inputReg.val()) {
        $.getJSON("api-proxy.php", { reg: inputReg.val() }, function( data ) {
            $("#car-make").val(data['make']);
            $("#car-model").val(data['model']);
        });
    } 
    else {
        alert('Please enter a registration number!');
    }
    return false;
})
```